# Are there currently no targeted New Shepard launches?

Tags: blue-origin, new-shepard

Blue Origin's New Shepard returned to flight last year. Yet it has become silent around the New Shepard since then and I can't find any further targeted flight dates of the New Shepard now. It seems that Blue Origin is currently focusing on the New Glenn (although its launch shall occur in August, it stands on the pad already for tests).

After the retirement of the VSS Unity this summer, the New Shepard will be the only means of suborbital space tourism. Are there currently no targeted launch dates of it? Does it even have a few waiting customers, like Virgin Galactic has several? IIRC Jeff Bezos wanted to announce the price for a spaceflight two years ago, but so far the New Shepard passengers paid much more than the VSS Unity spaceflight cost.

Comment: Blue Origin is extremely cautious when it comes to flying passengers on New Shepard. As an example they flew 15 straight successful capsules missions from 2015 to 2021 before making the first crewed flight. After six crewed missions in 12 months they had an anomaly on an uncrewed 2022 flight which grounded the program for 14 months. Return to flight was two months ago with an uncrewed mission. I expect they are still evaluating things and I expect the next flight will again be an uncrewed science mission.

Answer (score 0):

New Shepard last flew a bit over two months ago, which is not that long of a time for a rocket still under development. During the company's webcast of the 20 Dec 2023 launch,  Erika Wagner, a Blue Origin manager who co-hosted the webcast, [said](https://arstechnica.com/space/2023/12/blue-origins-suborbital-rocket-flies-for-first-time-in-15-months/)

> Following a thorough review of today’s mission, we look forward to flying our next crewed flight soon.

However, that nebulous soon may not mean "soon". Blue Origin is working on New Glenn and [appears to be on the verge of purchasing United Launch Alliance from Lockheed Martin and Boeing](https://arstechnica.com/space/2024/02/blue-origin-has-emerged-as-the-likely-buyer-for-united-launch-alliance/). Whether this means "soon", "soonish", "maybe", or "never" for the next New Shepard launch remains a big TBD (to be determined). Blue Origin hasn't commented.

Comment: It's not about how long ago they launched from today, but about still not having an approximate launch date which is something usually told months in advance, especially for crewed flights. And New Shepard isn't under development, it's the final version New Shepard 4. I also wonder who would fly on the mentioned crewed flight, as I don't think Blue Origin has as many waiting customers as Virgin Galactic since Blue Origin didn't mention a fixed price for a seat. Perhaps a research flight with scientists only.

Comment: @OldManJohn You appear to be asking for information that is currently held private by Blue Origin. It is their right to do so. I don't work for Blue, so I can only report information that has been made public. If some of our members do work for Blue, they would be highly remiss (and subject to job termination, or worse) if they reported internal communications that Blue deemed to be not yet ready for public release.

Answer (score 0):

[There are New Shepard launches planned.](https://spacenews.com/blue-origin-touts-capabilities-of-blue-ring-transfer-vehicle/)

> [Lars Hoffman, VP of national security sales at Blue Origin] said the company will increase the flight rate of New Shepard. A crewed flight, the first since August 2022, will take place “very soon,” he said, but he was not more specific. “We are definitely getting back on track this year with New Shepard,” he said. “We want to get on a nice pace or rhythm here where we’re launching regularly, mostly astronaut flights but there will be payload flights mixed in there as well.”

Comment: You are answering does Blue Origin ever plan to resume crewed New Shepard flights again, but I'm not sure that was the question. Although the word "targeted" can be interpreted different ways. Crewed launches of New Shepard had been steadily increasing in frequency, reaching a rate of every other month shortly before the accident. There was a successful uncrewed return to flight in mid December, yet so far no crewed flights have been announced. No NET date, estimated quarter, etc., at least that I know of. I suspect this may be what the OP is asking about.